# twice reading xml file with linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am trying to read xml file. and then extract some useful data to draw graphs.. I have achieved the desired output.. But the problem is my program is twice reading the xml file to extract the useful data.. This takes some extra time. Is there some other way to read the file once only. ? Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CanConformanceTesterLog Version="4.1">
  <TestProperties>
    <Item name="IUT Name" value="Reference"/>
    <Item name="PG Clock Period" value="1000 ns"/>
</TestProperties>
  <SignalData SamplingPeriod="1000.000 ns" DataWidth="16 bit">
    <Signal>
      <Id>IUT_RX</Id>
      <InitState>1</InitState>
      <![CDATA[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]]>
    </Signal>
    <Signal>
      <Id>IUT_TX</Id>
      <InitState>1</InitState>
      <![CDATA[SwVVBYcVkRWbFaUVrxW5FcMVzRXXFeEV6xX1Ff8VMRY7FkUWTxaBFosWlRafFqkWxxbRFtsW5RbvFgMXIRc/FxoYJBguGEwYVhh0GH4YsBi6GNgY4hgUGR4ZKBkyGVAZWhl4GYIZoBmqGb4Z6B4kH4ghxCETJB0kpyaxJrsmxSbPJgEnCyc9J0cnZSdvJ6EnqyfdJ+cnGSgjKC0oQShLKF8ocyiHKJsopSivKLkowyjyNCQ1LjVgNWo1nDWmNcQ1zjUANgo2FDYeNkY2UDZaNmQ2bjZ4NpY2qja0Nrg3]]>
    </Signal>
</SignalData>
</CanConformanceTesterLog>
```

I have function that reads the data of tag "SignalData".then after reading this data it calls another function and pass the name of xml file,dataWidth,samplingPeriod.
The second function then reads "Signal" tag.. and then extract the data from every "Signal". Finally when everything is done then a function is called to draw the graphs...

```
private bool SignalDataInfo(string fileName)
        {
            var xdoc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
            if (xdoc != null)
            {
                var signalData = xdoc.Descendants("SignalData");
                foreach (var signal in signalData)
                {
                    var width = signal.Attribute("DataWidth").Value;
                    string dataWidth = width.Substring(0, width.IndexOf(" "));
                    var period = signal.Attribute("SamplingPeriod").Value;
                    string samplingPeriod = period.Substring(0, period.IndexOf(" "));
                    SignalData(fileName,dataWidth, samplingPeriod);
                }
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }

public bool SignalData(string fileName,string width, string period)
        {var xdoc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
            if (xdoc != null)
            {
                var signalData = xdoc.Descendants("Signal");

                foreach (var signal in signalData)
                { // extract data from every signal }
return true;
else false;
}
```

Comment: Is it necessary to you to add new method to get data inside `Descendants("Signal")`? what if you can get this data in your first method's foreach?

Comment: This is trivially fixed by retaining the `xdoc` variable between calls. The description of your logic and the actual code presented do not match - it seems like you're glossing over the fact that you call `XDocument.Load` twice in separate contexts.  Have you made any attempts to retain the document in memory? Are there any obstacles you're faced with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I create a sample console app for you to extract data from both of your `SignalData` and `Signal`.

I think you would be in search of code like below.

In below code snippet you would use `result` in your program where you want to read data inside xml.

So by this way you don't need to write two different methods and load your xml each time when your methods called.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"Your xml document path");

        var result = (from o in doc.Descendants("SignalData")
                      from i in o.Descendants("Signal")
                      select new
                      {
                          dataWidth = o.Attribute("DataWidth").Value.Substring(0, o.Attribute("DataWidth").Value.IndexOf(" ")),
                          period = o.Attribute("SamplingPeriod").Value.Substring(0, o.Attribute("SamplingPeriod").Value.IndexOf(" ")),
                          Id = i.Elements("Id").Select(item => (string)item).FirstOrDefault(),
                          InitState = i.Elements("InitState").Select(item => (string)item).FirstOrDefault(),
                          cdata = i.Value
                      }).ToList();

        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"dataWidth: { item.dataWidth}, \t period: {item.period}, \t Id: {item.Id}, \t InitState: {item.InitState}");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**Output:** `cdata` excluded from output.

[image]

Comment: thanks. I have to brush up my linq skills.. But I am able to understand the code.. Thanks again..

Comment: Explaination in detail: In answer `o` means each element from descendant of `SignalData` and `i` means each element from descendant of `Signal` and in `select new` just project your each of element from `o` or `i` to anonymous type  :) Hope it will clears

Comment: @hamid, if you found answer helpful to you then please mark tick beside the answer :)

Comment: @hamid, Is any problem with my answer that u just unaccept it?

Comment: oh God, I am sorry.. I tried to accept that answer.. I thought that was unaccepted...

Comment: @hamid, oh no problem.. i m worried and think that is any problem with my answer. but in future if you need any help then ping me your question url in comment below :)

Comment: I am grateful to you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just load the XML file once by saving the XDocument that was loaded in a class variable (say `private XDocument xDoc;`) instead of creating an instance on each method. Also, it would help if you just retrieve the XML data separately, in this case, the `loadData()` method which you can use to initialize the data once. This will also give your code, somehow, separation of concerns. See code below:

```
private XDocument xDoc;

private void loadData(string fileName)
{
   xDoc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
}

private bool SignalDataInfo()
        {
            if (xDoc != null)
            {
                var signalData = xDoc.Descendants("SignalData");
                foreach (var signal in signalData)
                {
                    var width = signal.Attribute("DataWidth").Value;
                    string dataWidth = width.Substring(0, width.IndexOf(" "));
                    var period = signal.Attribute("SamplingPeriod").Value;
                    string samplingPeriod = period.Substring(0, period.IndexOf(" "));
                    SignalData(fileName,dataWidth, samplingPeriod);
                }
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }

public bool SignalData(string width, string period)
        {
            if (xDoc != null)
            {
                var signalData = xDoc.Descendants("Signal");

                foreach (var signal in signalData)
                { // extract data from every signal }
return true;
else false;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This class (whatever it maybe) has a public method, that you pass a filename too. Currently this implementation would have issues if you passed a filename that was different to the original doc that was loaded

Comment: You're right about that. I guess it would be better if he just created a separate method for retrieving the xml file, so this won't be a problem anymore.

Comment: if I pass  xdoc to second function as parameter then it will work. I think this is your suggestion.Am I right. ?

Comment: I think you're probably pushing the OP in the right direction with this, OP maybe should look at the class they are designed and make it so that you create a new instance injecting the filepath and then it doesn't change. if you want a different file you create a new instance of the class

Comment: @hamid not really that kind of solution, but instead, use a class variable and store the retrieved XML data in it. Then, you can use that class variable on both SignalDataInfo and SignalData method without retrieving the XML data on each of them.

Comment: @Dave Yes, I think that will help, too. Though, I don't want to make things too complicated right now. Maybe a simple separation of concern can help him fix the issue.